# Google Recaptcha V3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I would just like to check if anyone has a working example of Googles recaptcha using V3 with ASP.NET ?

I have got it to work locally but it seems like the response I am getting back does not include the score rating for the recaptcha ?

```
{
  "success": true,
  "challenge_ts": "2019-02-06T13:24:29Z",
  "hostname": "testkey.google.com"
}
```

That's the result I am getting back, I would like to implement V3 where I can get the score rating back. All examples online are in PHP.

My code:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My Controller to get the response:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FormSubmit()
{
    var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
    string secretKey = "MY_Secret_Key";

    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(),
        UseProxy = true
    };

    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var result = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format("api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, response)).Result;

            var jsonReturned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.